# Spring, MySQL and hibernate joining tables in one model

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

Spring, MySQL and hibernate joining tables in one model

I am working on a Spring, MySQL and Hibernate project and this is the first time the firm is asking me to do a join of tables within the java code.

in the pass I write code like the following to get list data back from Hibernate:

```
return (List<NameID_lookupModel>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(NameID_lookupModel.class)
                .addOrder( Order.asc("Name"))
                .list();
```

But in this new project I will be reading from more then one table so I need help geting my model setup right.

my tables look like this

table a, col 1 and col 2
table b, col 1 and col 2
table c, col 1 and col 2

I have to do a select on Table A where col 2 in Table B col1 but then join Table b col2 to Table c col 1.

How do I do this in a java model??

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches to your problem:

- use a view in the db and map your class to the view
- use SQL hibernate queries and take results as instances of the model class that you want to use (in your example something that will map table A); Example:

  `SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SQL THAT YOU WANT TO USE WITH THE JOINS AND WHERE");
  query.addEntity(LookupMappedModel.class);
  List<LookupMappedModel> result = (List<LookupMappedModel>)query.list();`

You can find more examples here: [Hibernate - Using a Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)